# Custom List View items

Tags: android, listview

I am writing code for a listview which has fixed number of rows and when the user scrolls the listview, instead of moving the list elements (views), I want to change the content of the views where as the list elements (views) stay at the there position.

For this I am returning a number Eg. 5 in getCount(), however I am no clue on how can I change contents of list items while keeping the list items in a fixed position.

Any help is welcomed.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

with [getItemAtPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition%28int%29)
you get the item at position, there you can change its content and then call [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) to signal the adapter that the data has changed.